# how to open port 10051

Tags: zabbix, firewalld

Zabbix server does not see the active port

10.150.26.101 - my ceph server
10.247.8.54 - my zabbix proxy server

firewall on target server
OS centOS7

```
[root@ceph-02 ~]# firewall-cmd --info-service=zabbix-agent2
 zabbix-agent2
 ports: 10050/tcp 10051/tcp
 protocols:
 source-ports:
 modules:
 destination:
```

availability from a ceph server:

```
[root@ceph-02 ~]# telnet 10.247.8.54 10050
 Trying 10.247.8.54...
 Connected to 10.247.8.54.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 Connection closed by foreign host.
 [root@ceph-02 ~]# telnet 10.247.8.54 10051
 Trying 10.247.8.54...
 Connected to 10.247.8.54.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

availability from a proxy server:

```
[root@zbx-proxy ~]# telnet 10.150.26.101 10050
 Trying 10.150.26.101...
 Connected to 10.150.26.101.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 Connection closed by foreign host.
 [root@zbx-proxy ~]# telnet 10.150.26.101 10051
 Trying 10.150.26.101...
 telnet: connect to address 10.150.26.101: Connection refused
```

log from zabbix agent:

```
2021/08/17 02:46:13.629379 [101] active check configuration update from [zbx-proxy.domain.loc:10051 ceph-02.domain.loc] started to fail (Cannot read message: 'read tcp 10.150.26.101:60011->10.247.8.54:10051: i/o timeout')
```

Zabbix server refuses to call a session on the active port of zabbix agent2 even though all ports are open, what could be the matter?

Comment: `what could be the matter?` zabbix agent ignores the connection, or there is something else between the server and the clinet.

Comment: your `ServerActive` agent configuration is probably wrong, update question including all non-commented settings in your `agentd.conf`